# Problema para meter datos de una base de datos SQLite a un ListView con Java y android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Disculpen tengo un problema la querer agregar datos a una base de datos, en realidad al parecer los datos si se ingresan mas no los puedo mostrar en una list View, quisiera saber cual es el problema porque la consola no me arroja ningún problema y tampoco errores ni nada aquí el siguiente es el código:

> package com.example.leaftime.rocketdefender;
>
> /**  * Created by Leaftime on 04/11/2017.  */
>
> public class User {
>       private Integer id;
>       private String name;
>       private Integer score;
>
> ```
> public User(Integer id, String name, Integer score)
> {
>     this.id = id;
>     this.name = name;
>     this.score = score;
> }
>
> public Integer getId() {
>     return id;
> }
>
> public void setId(Integer id) {
>     this.id = id;
> }
>
> public String getName() {
>     return name;
> }
>
> public void setName(String name) {
>     this.name = name;
> }
>
> public Integer getScore() {
>     return score;
> }
>
> public void setScore(Integer score) {
>     this.score = score;
> } }
> ```

-- lo de arriba es la clase User() que pasa los datos de mis items

> import android.database.Cursor; import
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.ListView;
>
> import com.example.leaftime.rocketdefender.utils.utility;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> public class HighscoreListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>       ListView highscoreList;
>
> ```
> ArrayList<String> listInfo;
> ArrayList<User> listUsers;
>
> ConectionSQLiteHelper conn;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
> {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_highscore_list);
>
>     conn = new ConectionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), "bd users", null, 1);
>
>     highscoreList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.highscoreList);
>
>     getListPersons();
>
>     ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listInfo);
>     highscoreList.setAdapter(adapter);
> }
>
> private void getListPersons()
> {
>     SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
>
>     User user;
>     listUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
>     //select * from users
>     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + utility.TABLE_USER, null);
>
>     while(cursor.moveToNext())
>     {
>         user = new User(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2));
>
>         listUsers.add(user);
>     }
>     obtainList();
> }
>
> private void obtainList()
> {
>     listInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < listUsers.size(); i++)
>     {
>         listInfo.add(listUsers.get(i).getId() + " - " + listUsers.get(i).getName());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

-- lo de arriba es la clase del Activity al cual le mando los items para parsearlos al ListView en forma de String pero al agregar la opción me lleva a esta pantalla pero sin agregar ningún item y no sé cual sería el problema.
Como les comento la base de datos no esta vacía si tiene items, pero no se pueden mostrar, gracias de antemano si necesitan cualquier otra parte del código haganmelo saber solamente he puesto lo más importante.

Comment: Si desarrollas en Android y deseas encontrar un problema en tu aplicación porque no revisas el LogCat? Eso evitará estar adivinando que posibles problemas tendría tu aplicación. Agrega el mensaje de error que encuentres.

Comment: es justamente por eso que no encuentro el error, el logcat no me tira ningun error ni nada

Comment: Y la clase del adaptador, ¿la podrías mostrar? Recuerda que tienes que notificar al adaptador cuanto tienes nueva data que mostrar.

Comment: Estas seguro que tienes data? Otra cosa, no te olvides de cerrar el cursor y la db

Comment: para este tipo de problemas existe el DEBUG te ayudara paso a paso hasta encontrar el erro ;)